# easiest way to subtract numbers

Tags: unix, sed

I would like to subtract 2 numbers in this line and have the result at the end of the line, like this example:

```
numbers ; 20.55  ; 10.55
```

so I have the result

```
numbers ; 20.55  ; 10.55  ; -10
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` would be a better tool than `sed` for this purpose

```
awk -F\; '{print $0, $3-$2}' OFS=" ; "
```

**Example**

```
$ awk -F\; '{print $0, $3-$2}' OFS=" ; " input
numbers ; 20.55 ; 10.55 ; -10
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer. I've never used awk before but I understand what it does now and  this is indeed a way easier command for this.